# Lilypond custom lines to denote intervals

Tags: lilypond

I'm trying to display the harmonic series, and highlight the interval between each note and the octave below them. I'm imagining dimension lines as used in blue-prints. I could use some hints on how to do this.

[image]

My first try was to use [`Voice.TupletBracket`](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/internals/tupletbracket).

```
{
  \clef bass
  \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = ##f
  \override Score.BarLine.stencil = ##f
  \time 16/4
  \tupletUp
  bes,,,4_"1"
  \tuplet 5/5 { bes,,_"2" f,_"3" }
  \tuplet 5/5 { \tuplet 3/3 { bes,_"4" d_"5" } f_"6" } geseh_"7"
  \tuplet 8/8 { \tuplet 7/7 { \tuplet 5/5 { \tuplet 3/3 { \tuplet 2/2 { bes_"8" c'_"9" } d'_"10" } eeh'_"11" f'_"12" } geh'_"13" gih'_"14" a'_"15" } bes'_"16" }
}
```

[image]

This is almost exactly what I want.  I have the straight brackets, and the numbers are great.  But the main issue is that I'd also like the octaves marked.  To do that, I'd need the `bes` notes to end the previous tuple before they start the next one.  I tried `\tuplet 8/8 \=1{ bes \tuplet 8/8 \=2{ bes \=1} ...`, but lilypond caught fire.  I'd also like the lines to be horizontal, but `max-slope-factor` isn't available in my version of lilypond (2.24).

But thinking of the `\=1(` notation my next thought was to use slurs which do support that notation.

```
  bes,,,4_"1"  ^\=8(                                                
  bes,,_"2"    \=8) ^\=8( ^\=5( 
  f,_"3"       \=5)                                                             
  bes,_"4"     \=8) ^\=8( ^\=5( ^\=3(
  d_"5"        \=3)                                                             
  f_"6"        \=5)   
  bes_"8"      \=8)  ...
```

[image]

Now I have all of the spanners I need (including the octaves), but this clearly looks awful. I'm having trouble setting offsets for only one slur at a time. They all start at the same point so an `\override` is not going to target only one.  I also spent a ton of time offsetting that text above the slurs.  Even if I could set the control points for individual slurs that start at the same point, they would be smooth, while I like the jagged look of the other lines.

My next thought was `TextSpanner` but after an hour of looking up how to make them overlap, I realize that \stopTextSpan cannot point to a specific line, and so it is not possible to make them overlap.

[image]

My next thought is markup.  I think this is promising.  After struggling with `define-markup-command` for a while, I just brute-forced it and wrote part of it out manually.

```
  bes,,,4^\markup{\center-column{ "8" \rotate #270 \left-brace #25 } }
  bes,,^\markup{\center-column{ "5" \rotate #270 \left-brace #25 } }^\markup{\center-column{ "8" \rotate #270 \left-brace #50 } }
  f,
  bes,^\markup{\center-column{ "3" \rotate #270 \left-brace #25 } }^\markup{\center-column{ "5" \rotate #270 \left-brace #50 } }^\markup{\center-column{ "8" \rotate #270 \left-brace #100 }}
  ...
```

[image]

This might have potential but the horizontal space between the brace and the number really look bad, and the vertical scaling of the brace is a no-go.  I'm not sure if that white-space is from the `\rotate #270` taking up a row, or if it is kerning of the bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to make the tuplets work is to create an empty note and extend the tuplet over it.  To ensure the bracket extends to the next note, tweak the `TupletBracket.X-positions`:

```
\tweak TupletBracket.X-positions #'(1 . 7)
\tuplet 8/8 {
  bes,,,4
  \once \override NoteHead.stencil = ##f
  \once \override Stem.stencil = ##f
  bes,,,
}
```

In lilypond >=2.25, you can ensure each bracket is horizontal with the `TupletBracket.max-slope-factor`

```
\override TupletBracket.max-slope-factor = #0
```

In lilypond <= 2.24, to achieve that you need to manually set the Y-coordinates of each bar:

```
\tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(4.5 . 4.5)
\tuplet 2/2 {
  bes_"8"
  c'_"9"
}
```

The final solution:

[image]

```
\version "2.24.1"
{
  \clef bass
  \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = ##f
  \override Score.BarLine.stencil = ##f
  \time 16/4
  \tupletUp

  \tweak TupletBracket.X-positions #'(1 . 7.)
  \tuplet 8/8 {
    bes,,,4_"1"
    \once \override NoteHead.stencil = ##f
    \once \override Stem.stencil = ##f
    bes,,,
  }
  \tweak TupletBracket.X-positions #'(1.2 . 10.8)
  \tuplet 8/8 {
    \tuplet 5/5 {
      bes,,_"2"
      f,_"3"
    }
    \once \override NoteHead.stencil = ##f
    \once \override Stem.stencil = ##f
    bes,
  }
  \tweak TupletBracket.X-positions #'(1.2 . 19)
  \tuplet 8/8 {
    \tuplet 5/5 {
      \tuplet 3/3 {
        bes,_"4" 
      d_"5"
      }
      f_"6"
    }
    \once \override Voice.NoteHead.color = #(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
    \once \override Voice.Stem.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
    \once \override Voice.Accidental.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
    geseh_"7"
  }

  \tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(10.5 . 10.5)
  \tuplet 8/8 {
    \tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(9 . 9)
    \tuplet 7/7 {
      \tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(7.5 . 7.5)
      \tuplet 5/5 {
        \tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(6 . 6)
        \tuplet 3/3 {
          \tweak TupletBracket.positions #'(4.5 . 4.5)
          \tuplet 2/2 {
            bes_"8"
            c'_"9"
          }
          d'_"10"
        }
        \once \override Voice.NoteHead.color = #(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
        \once \override Voice.Stem.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
        \once \override Voice.Accidental.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
        eeh'_"11"
        f'_"12"
      }
      \override Voice.NoteHead.color = #(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
      \override Voice.Stem.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
      \override Voice.Accidental.color = $(rgb-color 0.8 0.2 0.2)
      geh'_"13"
      gih'_"14"
      \revert Voice.NoteHead.color
      \revert Voice.Stem.color
      \revert Voice.Accidental.color
      a'_"15"
    }
    bes'_"16"
  }
}
\layout {
  \context {
    \Score
    \override SpacingSpanner.common-shortest-duration = #(ly:make-moment 1/16)
  }
}
```

If you use the same `\tweak TupletBracket.positions` for all 8, 5, and 3s then you get this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not manually offset your Slurs? Instead of doing `\override` (which changes the defaults for the context) change each single Slur individually doing

```
\tweak extra-offset #'(0 . 2) (
```

Generally the issue here are restritions at an engraver level. So the best idea would probably be to create a custom engraver for this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look up custom engravers.